# Why does Postgresql use a (parallel) sequential scan instead of index scan in this query?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have the following table:

```sql
create table images
(
    image_id       bigint,
    image          text,
    url            text,
    post_id        bigint,
    checksum       text,
    path           varchar
);


create index images_postid_idx
    on images (post_id);

create index image_2020_idx
    on images (image);
```

(Yes, there is no primary key! Also there are few other fields that are mostly null and are not relevant for the query.)

This very simple query:

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM images where image = 'foo';
```

produces the following execution plan:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..40080349.00 rows=93 width=4) (actual time=339826.750..339933.048 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 10
  Workers Launched: 10
  Buffers: shared hit=527195 read=39504582 dirtied=23
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on images  (cost=0.00..40079339.70 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=339800.607..339800.607 rows=0 loops=11)
        Filter: (image = 'foo'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3459138
        Buffers: shared hit=527195 read=39504582 dirtied=23
Planning Time: 3.684 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 34
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 4.039 ms, Inlining 382.076 ms, Optimization 121.531 ms, Emission 71.917 ms, Total 579.563 ms"
Execution Time: 339978.002 ms
```

What could be the cause of that problem? I copied the table, put on the same indices and copied a few thousands rows => everything worked fine there. I also ran `ANALYSE images` to update stats.

I am not sure why the planner doesn't use the index on this table. There are 28,091,491 distinct values for `image` out of 380,000,000 rows total. Since my query actually doesn't select anything from the table, why would the planner ever choose something other than an Index-Only Scan?

I am using PG 12.5.

Update:
Output of `select * from pg_stats where tablename = 'images' and attname = 'image';`: https://pastebin.com/Xeg7DjQd

Update 2:
Output of `\d+ images`:

```
                                      Table "public.images"
     Column     |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 image_id       | bigint            |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 image          | text              |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 url            | text              |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 post_id        | bigint            |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 checksum       | text              |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 path           | character varying |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 field1         | numeric           |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 field2         | numeric           |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 field3         | integer           |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 field4         | numeric           |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 field5         | double precision  |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 field6         | double precision  |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "image_2020_idx" btree (image)
    "images_postid_idx" btree (post_id)
Replica Identity: FULL
Access method: heap
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the **unbounded** `text` type instead of `varchar(n)`? Generally speaking it's a bad idea to use unbounded types because unintentional massive data input can bring your database to its knees.

Comment: No particular reason. I never had any issue with this. Since the used storage is the same I guess the creator of the table just wasn't aware of that. (Or like I - until just now - thought there is a maximum length of 255 for `varchar` columns.)

Comment: `28,091,491 distinct values for image out of 380,000,000 rows total.` <<-- put images into a separate table and refer to that via a FK.

Comment: Maybe the index is in an invalid state. Try `reindex` to rebuild it.

Comment: @Dai: no, not with Postgres. There is absolutely no difference in speed or storage requirement between `text` or `varchar(n)` (if both store the same strings)

Comment: @user1068464: no 255 is not a magic number for a varchar length.

Comment: @wildplasser I plan to do that, however, I don't know if this is a related issue. The result would still be the same amount of distinct values - just a little bit more compact because I could use int (or bigint) instead of varchar/text. How would this help the index?

Comment: @jjanes I did a reindex, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Very strange.  How about if you `set enable_seqscan=off` first?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited the more detailed explain output.

Comment: @jjanes Already did that, did not help either.

Comment: Does it change if you turn jit off? `set jit=off;`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, the output is virtually the same (except the jit information and some numbers because of table growth).

Comment: Very strange, and  I can't reproduce it.  But it looks like you have only about 38e6 rows (3459138 * 11), not 380e6.  And each row is in a page by itself?

Comment: Can you execute the following query and post the results? select * from pg_stats where tablename = 'images' and attname = 'image';

Comment: @steve Output is a bit clunky, but I put a pastebin link in the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know `text` is different in Postgres compared to MSSQL, but my comment was about the risk of unsanitized user-input causing 100MB+ of text to be stored in an unbounded textual column which would have been caught by a _reasonable_ max-length value. I mention it because that actually did happen to me once.

Comment: The number of distinct values is only 374436. The index is not selective.

Comment: `Yes, there is no primary key!` You should. This table looks like a denormalised 1:N, or even N:M relation. This is not a database table, it is a spreadsheet with indexes.

Comment: There is no point in picking that index, a parallel seq scan will be faster.

Comment: @steve No, the condition is very selective, and PostgreSQL should definitely use the index. What is the output of `\d images` in `psql`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I updated the question and put the output of `\d+ images` there.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't disagree, but as it is now, there is no "natural" primary key and adding one would just increase the table size. The table schema will be updated, but it's not that easy, since multiple processes need to be changed for this and I don't see the relation between this issue and the issue of the index not being used.

Comment: A table without a primary key has no meaning. Fix your data model before trying to *optimise* (what are the cardinalities of image, url or path? do they depend on image_id and/or post_id?

Comment: I see nothing wring there. Like everybody else, I have no explanation.

Comment: @wildplasser This data is fetched from a source not under our control. Our data model therefore depends on the source's data model, which is something we didn't know much when this table started and we still don't know 100% yet. As I said, I know this is something that needs to be addressed, but unless there is a documented issue where having no primary key can affect an index not being used, I regard this as separate issues. I would like to know what's going on here - even if it is just for academic purposes and a solution with a clean data model would use the index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the table was actually way too big. It used almost 300GB of disk space, when in reality it should have only used ~ 10GB. I tried a normal `VACUUM` which didn't help, `VACUUM FULL` (which I avoided to run, because I assumed it will need 300 GB space) , however, did. When the table shrunk to that size the index got used correctly.

However, I have no idea how the table could accumulate that much dead space with auto_vacuum on. Also according to the people using this table, they didn't even do any mass deletions, so that part is still a mystery.